# C crypt() function, different passwords, same hash

Tags: c, encryption, cs50, crypt

The below code is producing the same **hash** for **different but similar words**. Does this mean that the user can type a similar password and get the access?

```
hi  = crypt("academics", "50");
hii = crypt("academicians", "50");

printf ("academics : %s\n", hi);
printf ("academicians : %s\n", hii);

printf ("string compare : %d\n", strcmp(hi,hii));
```

> **output :**

```
academics      : 50IlqAh9rdDJo
academicians   : 50IlqAh9rdDJo
string compare : 0
```

Comment: For password hashes the SHA family is widely used: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms

Comment: @ErikMüller Yeah, it is, unfortunately because that's not what they are meant for. You should be using a [password hash or PBKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). bcrypt comes to mind, while we're speaking of crypt. Recommending a cryptographic hash instead of password hash is outright dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

They `crypt` function uses the lowest 7 bits of each of the first eight characters of the key you pass as a parameter in order to generate the key that is used for encryption.

Comment: ... and should really not be used anymore, if just for above reasons. Use a modern variant like bcrypt, scrypt etc.